# Coldfusion: Uploading and inserting into MYSQL database

Tags: sql, coldfusion, cfc

Here's the problem:

I have form with some user info, I need to attach a picture. I've got everything setup the way it needs to go, but when I process the form, it uploads the file and then inserts this into the database:

```
> D:\ColdFusion8\runtime\servers\coldfusion\SERVER-INF\temp\wwwroot-tmp\neotmp52353.tmp
```

Yet the file exists at:

```
./uploads/imagen1.jpg
```

This is a piece of my form:

```
<cfform action="process_person.cfm"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<cfinput type="file" required="no"  name="Photo">
```

This is the processor, which his the CFC file:

```
<cfinvoke component="cfc/certifcations" method="add">

<cffile action="upload" filefield="Photo" destination="#destination#" nameConflict="makeUnique" result="upload">
 <cfdump var="#upload#">
<cfinvokeargument name="Photo" value="#Form.Photo#">
```

This is the CFC piece:

```
 <cfargument name="photo" type="string" required="no">
```

I need the ./uploads/imagen1.jpg inserted into the database not the tmp file. Where am I going wrong? THe file is uploading correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I had result specified to upload.

What I did was remove that, then set #cffile.serverFile# in my value for my cfinvokeargument. That gave me the file name. Now I am working on getting the path. I hope this helps!

Comment: Fyi: It works with the result attribute too. Just pass the #yourResultName.serverFile# as the argument (instead of #Form.Photo#)